# Pygame.midi.init() function errors

Tags: pygame, debian, midi, alsa

I can't call the pygame.midi.init() function on my Debian machine. Running the following code:

```
import pygame, pygame.midi
pygame.midi.init()
```

will result in the following errors:

> ALSA lib conf.c:3009:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /etc/alsa/alsa.conf
>
> ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default

Can any one help?
PS: i am using Debian 9.2

Comment: Do other ALSA tools (e.g., `aplay -l`) work when run as the same user?

Comment: yes aplay works!

Comment: Does the mentioned file exist? What are its permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a link to the `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` did the work:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf /etc/alsa/alsa.conf`